# DarkSky API - Unhandled rejection Error - ReactJS / Axios / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

Wondering if you can help out, I'm a but stumped on this one...

I have a travel app in React, where users can locate other users online, (once the logged in users lat and lng has been located).

Once located, on my web app page - I use the lng/lng, to pull through Zomato api local info/restaurants.  This used to work, but now I get the following error in my console...   (This used to work, but the code hasn't changed...)

I'm trying to do the same with DarkSky api, to pull through local weather data. And I've structured my axios request exactly the same. However, this doesn't work either.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
app.js:55642 Unhandled rejection Error: Request failed with status code 
400
at createError (http://localhost:8000/app.js:9175:15)
at settle (http://localhost:8000/app.js:53028:12)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (http://localhost:8000/app.js:9048:7)
From previous event:
at Hub._this.getPlaces (http://localhost:8000/app.js:53788:26)
at commitCallbacks (http://localhost:8000/app.js:38450:15)
at commitLifeCycles (http://localhost:8000/app.js:41688:13)
at commitAllLifeCycles (http://localhost:8000/app.js:43345:9)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback 
(http://localhost:8000/app.js:32010:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev 
(http://localhost:8000/app.js:32048:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:8000/app.js:32097:29)
at commitRoot (http://localhost:8000/app.js:43484:9)
at completeRoot (http://localhost:8000/app.js:44381:36)
at performWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:8000/app.js:44331:11)
at performWork (http://localhost:8000/app.js:44249:9)
at performSyncWork (http://localhost:8000/app.js:44226:5)
at requestWork (http://localhost:8000/app.js:44126:7)
at scheduleWorkImpl (http://localhost:8000/app.js:44001:13)
printWarning @ app.js:55642
formatAndLogError @ app.js:55358
fireRejectionEvent @ app.js:55383
Promise._notifyUnhandledRejection @ app.js:54829
(anonymous) @ app.js:54808
setTimeout (async)
Promise._ensurePossibleRejectionHandled @ app.js:54807
Promise._reject @ app.js:57521
Promise._settlePromise @ app.js:57447
Promise._settlePromise0 @ app.js:57477
Promise._settlePromises @ app.js:57552
(anonymous) @ app.js:54272
Promise.then (async)
schedule @ app.js:58581
Async.settlePromises @ app.js:54271
Promise._reject @ app.js:57519
Promise._rejectCallback @ app.js:57337
PromiseArray._reject @ app.js:57777
PromiseArray._promiseRejected @ app.js:57797
Promise._settlePromise @ app.js:57439
Promise._settlePromise0 @ app.js:57477
Promise._settlePromises @ app.js:57552
(anonymous) @ app.js:54272
Promise.then (async)
schedule @ app.js:58581
Async.settlePromises @ app.js:54271
Promise._reject @ app.js:57519
Promise._rejectCallback @ app.js:57337
reject @ app.js:59005
geocode:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 
of 404 ()
```

I can access the data/api call via Invision, or other tools, when I plug in the lat lng manually. So I know the api is working.  Here's an example:

***https://api.darksky.net/forecast/MY_API_KEY/50.830133,-0.137434***

However, there is something wrong in how I'm trying to make my Axios request working in my react JSX.

Here's the relevantcode of my page, (api keys hidden).

Any help would be great - I'm not sure why I can't console.log the weather data as a starting point.

And why my zomato data isn't changing, based on the users lat lng coordinates.

```
"class Hub extends React.Component {

state =  {
 places: null,
 articles: null,
 user: null,
 lat: null,
 lng: null,
 weather: null
}

setLocation = (lat, lng) => {
 console.log('location set...', lat, lng);
 this.setState({ lat: lat, lng: lng }, this.getPlaces);
}

getWeather = () => {
const params = {lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng};

//restaurants
Promise.props({
  weather: axios({
    url: 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast',
    params: params,
    json: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'user-key': 'MY_API_KEY'}
  }).then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      weather: data.weather
    });
  });

 }

 getPlaces = () => {
   const params = { count: 3, lat: 34.019864, lon: -118.490541 };
   if(this.state.lat && this.state.lng) {
   Object.assign(params, { lat: this.state.lat, lon: this.state.lng });
 }

 //restaurants
 Promise.props({
  restaurants: axios({
    url: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode',
    params: params,
    json: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'user-key': 'MY_API_KEY'}
  }).then(res => res.data),
  articles: axios({
    url: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/collections',
    params: params,
    json: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'user-key': 'MY_API_KEY'}
  }).then(res => res.data)
 })
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      places: data.restaurants.nearby_restaurants.slice(0, 6),
      articles: data.articles.collections
    });
  });
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.getPlaces();
  this.getWeather();
 }

 render() {
  etc etc etc
 }
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, 

I don't think thats it, because this plugged in lat/lng:

      const params = {count: 3, lat: 34.019864, lon: -118.490541 };

...returns results for the location LA.  What isn't happening, is the lat lon being updated, once a users location is found.  So it should update with London lat lng for example.  Therefore, changing the restaurant data displayed on the page, to london restaurants...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the API key and coordinates should be [part of the path](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#forecast-request). try:

```
  weather: axios({
    url: `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${MY_API_KEY}/${params.lat},${params.lng}`, // add api key to the path
    json: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'user-key': 'MY_API_KEY'}
  })
```

Comment: ok, if I do that, I get the following error:

    Failed to load https://api.darksky.net/forecast/$%7B75f4aa767c9a552f37a6a6fc099f84f6%7D/$%7Bparams.lat%7D,$%7Bparams.lng%7D: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: The data is definitely being pulled in already, by my plugged in Los Angeles lat lng, as restaurant data is appearing on my page from zomato.  But it doesn't update the coordinates, once my location/lat lng is found.

This lat/lng is not being parsed through...

Comment: Hi, first remove your API key from the comment :), it looks like your'e encoding the URL which turns the interpolation into $%7B.

Comment: In other words use: 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/' + MY_API_KEY + '/' + params.lat + ',' + params.lng

Comment: Ok, thank you i tried that, but then I get the following....

ok, if I do that, I get the following error: Failed to load api.darksky.net/forecast/…: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8000'; is therefore not allowed access

Comment: Then you should probably access their test API or use hosts file (with port 80) to communicate from your white-listed domain.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how would i do this?
If you log into the site here and go to /hub, you can see how it's working:
https://hit-me-up-app.herokuapp.com/hub

Do you think this has something to do with Google's M70 lock down on SSL certificates? 

I also get this in console too:
The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://developers.zomato.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.